# Improvements in implementing MVP in Android

Tags: android, mvp

I am implementing MVP architecture, code works fine, I wanted your suggestions if I there can be improvements done or in any areas where I am not following the pattern correctly.

It is a simple application using RecyclerViews to list games in a Fragment.

FGames - Fragment which displays the list of Games

```
public class FGames extends Fragment implements GamesView {

    @BindView(R.id.rv_games)
    RecyclerView rvGames;
    private GamesAdapter gamesAdapter;
    private GamesPresenterImpl presenter;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.games_layout, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        presenter = new GamesPresenterImpl(this);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        presenter.initUi();
    }

    @Override
    public void initRecyclerView(List<GameEntity> gameEntities) {
        gamesAdapter = new GamesAdapter(getActivity(), gameEntities);
        rvGames.setAdapter(gamesAdapter);
        rvGames.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    }
}
```

Interface - GamesView

```
  public interface GamesView {

        /**
         * Initialise the recycler view to list Games data
         * @param gameEntities
         */
        void initRecyclerView(List<GameEntity> gameEntities);
    }
```

GamesPresenterImpl - Presenter implementation

```
    public class GamesPresenterImpl implements GamesPresenter {

    GamesView gamesView;

    public GamesPresenterImpl(GamesView gamesView) {
        this.gamesView = gamesView;
    }

    @Override
    public void initUi() {
        gamesView.initRecyclerView(getGamesData());
    }

    public List<GameEntity> getGamesData() {
        List<GameEntity> gameEntities = new ArrayList<>();
        int counter = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
            GameEntity gameEntity = new GameEntity();
            counter ++;
            gameEntity.setName("Test name " + counter);
            gameEntity.setJackpot(100000055);
            gameEntities.add(gameEntity);
        }
        return gameEntities;
    }
}
```

Interface - GamesPresenter

```
public interface GamesPresenter {
    void initUi();
}
```

Thanks in advance
R

Comment: code reviews go on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I was never aware of that one. thanks. Why a down vote?

Comment: initUi() is part of UI is not in presenter class. It should be in activity class.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a 3rd layer where you can add you all data fetch (API/database) logic.
Refer http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidArchitecture/article.html

So your data population part will move to the 3rd layer

```
for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
  GameEntity gameEntity = new GameEntity();
    counter ++;
            gameEntity.setName("Test name " + counter);
            gameEntity.setJackpot(100000055);
            gameEntities.add(gameEntity);
}
```